# Batch class for Updating Username

Tags: scheduled-apex

I am new to Salesforce Programming. I was checking ways to update the username field of User record to always match with the Email field.

Can we write a batch class in achieving this? Thoughts

```
global class BatchUpdateAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{ 

global string query; 
global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){ 
   query = 'select Id,name,username,email from User 
             where Username<>email'; 
   return Database.getQueryLocator(query); 
} 
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope){
 List<User> cons = new List<User>(); 
 for (User s : scope){ 
   s.Username= s.Email; 
   cons.add(s); 
 } 
 update cons; 
} 
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){ } }
```

Comment: Should be possible with batch class. Its like updating any other record. Note: Username is unique field across all salesforce orgs. How would you handle that? Usually people append a prefix at the end of email in username

Comment: I would like to do it in Prod environment. So that would not require any prefix correct?

Comment: In that case it's possible and should be fairly easy. Let us know if you run into any specific issue.

Comment: You must use try-catch to handle any exception occur.

Comment: The error which I see in the job is  First error: expecting a colon, found 'email'

Comment: It should be a manual one time activity using dataloader. Why use batch?

Comment: We have communities enabled in the org. So when a user changes their email, we want the username to always match with it. Since there is a system limitation to update username based on change in email, I wanted to write a scheduled batch

Comment: I did try that as well.

Comment: global class BatchUpdateAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
global string query;

global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){
           query = 'select Id,name,username,email from User where Username__c= true';
    
          return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope){
  
  List<User> cons = new List<User>();

     for (User s : scope){
      
      s.Username= s.Email;
      cons.add(s);
  }

  update cons;    
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){  
}
}

Answer (score 2):

You can't write a SOQL filter to look for `User.Usernames` that don't agree with `User.Email`

Instead, if you want to do this in one SOQL, you'll need to create a Checkbox formula field on User that is

```
Is_UserName_Same_As_UserEmail__c
```

defined as `UserName = Email`

and query on that field as in `... where Is_UserName_Same_As_UserEmail__c = true`

Comment: I did try that as well. But it did not work

Comment: global class BatchUpdateAccount implements Database.Batchable<sObject>{
global string query;
global database.querylocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC){

           query = 'select Id,name,username,email from User where Username__c= true';
      return Database.getQueryLocator(query);

}
global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<User> scope){  
  List<User> cons = new List<User>();
     for (User s : scope){
            s.Username= s.Email;
      cons.add(s);
  }

  update cons;    
}
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC){  
}
}

Comment: @user43146 - you need to show your formula field for `Username__c` (BTW, boolean formula fields should usually be of the form IsXXX or HasYYY to indicate through reading into one's mind a true/false statement

Comment: The formula field Username__c is Email<>Username